# Flatten a string array field in a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image: Flat]

I want to flatten the `barcode` field of type `StringType`, instead of looking like this where there is more than one `barcode` for the same item, I want it to repeat, for example:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|suborder| updated_on | suborder_item_id| barcode            | 
+--------+------------+-----------------+--------------------+                         
|1       | 123        | 3333            |["123","456","789"] |
+--------+------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

I want it to repeat if there's more than one `barcode` in the same dataframe:

```
+--------+----------+----------------+-------+
|suborder|updated_on|suborder_item_id|barcode|
+--------+----------+----------------+-------+
|       1|       123|            3333|    123|
|       1|       123|            3333|    456|
|       1|       123|            3333|    789|
+--------+----------+----------------+-------+
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated, I've been struggling with this for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for just the `explode` function.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

……

df = df.select('suborder', 'updated_on', 'suborder_item_id', F.explode('barcode').alias('barcode'))
```

Comment: The problem is that the list is stored as a StringType() I'm gettting cannot 'explode(`barcode`)\' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map, not string

Answer (score 0):

Use `from_json` function to parse the stringified array into `ArrayType` then explode it:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 123, 3333, '["123","456","789"]')
], ["suborder", "updated_on", "suborder_item_id", "barcode"])

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "barcode",
    F.explode(F.from_json("barcode", "array<string>"))
)

df1.show()
#+--------+----------+----------------+-------+
#|suborder|updated_on|suborder_item_id|barcode|
#+--------+----------+----------------+-------+
#|       1|       123|            3333|    123|
#|       1|       123|            3333|    456|
#|       1|       123|            3333|    789|
#+--------+----------+----------------+-------+
```